# Removing extra <p> tags inside the class if it is more than 1 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, types

Hello Experts is there any way to remove existing p tags inside the class? if it is more than 1 using JavaScript.

Example:

```
 <div class='classname'>
    <p>Lorem ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
    </div>`
```

Expected Result:

```
<div class='classname'>
         <p>Lorem ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
```

Comment: Seems you have just posted a few moments ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `document.querySelectorAll('.classname > p')` it will return all `p` elements,then from second element remove it

```js
let peles = document.querySelectorAll('.classname > p')
for(let i=1;i<peles.length;i++){
   peles[i].remove()
}
```

```html
<div class='classname'>
    <p>Lorem ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
</div>
```

---

Update

If there are more `divs`,then you can using following

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.classname')
for(div of divs){
  let ps = div.querySelectorAll('p')
  for(let i=1;i<ps.length;i++){
    ps[i].remove()
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='classname'>
    <p>Lorem ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
</div>

<div class='classname'>
    <p>Lorem ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to enforce this every time, you might not even need to check how many `<p>` elements are inside the classname, and just remove all but the first child.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.classname > p:nth-of-type(n+2)');
elements.forEach(e => e.remove());
```

```html
<div class="classname">
  <p>1. Lorem ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor vel ex placerat, non imperdiet dolor lacinia. </p>
  <p>2. Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
  <p>3. Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
  <p>4. Lorem ipsum m ip purus hendrerit quam. Mauris convallis dolor v </p>
</div>
```

This code takes advantage of the CSS selector `:nth-of-type` which will select all `p` elements (In case you want to have other type of tags in there)
And also the [functional notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#functional_notation) `n+2` which offsets our selection to spare the first child.